# How do I construct an object that holds a reference to a parent using a weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, constructor, weak-ptr

Say I have an object that contains a shared_ptr to a child object.

I want the child object to have a weak_ptr to the parent object, what should the child object's constructor look like and how should I construct a child from the parent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What other objects does the "parent" share ownership of the "child" with? Does the "child" have multiple parents?

Comment: The child has one parent always, childs are not shared

Comment: In that case the child can hold a raw pointer to its parent as the child is guaranteed not to outlive its parent. Do you have not have access to a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: That makes sense, no need for smart pointers thank you!

Comment: Using a raw pointer works, but seems uglier than need be. Is there really no better smart pointer solution?

Comment: @peachykeen: A raw pointer is simpler. Why would you want to use a smart pointer when it's not necessary?

Comment: @CharlesBailey In the case of a weak_ptr, it allows the child to temporarily lock the parent and prevent any function (child or external) from destroying it for the duration of the child call. Potentially useful in a threaded environment, depending on the expected side effects of the child object. More toward opinion, mixing raw and smart pointers in the same code or class seems prone to causing trouble later.

Comment: @peachykeen: In a multithreaded situation where you have one thread trying to delete an object hierarchy while another thread calling functions on the same objects then you have threading issues that require locking. It seems unlikely to me that simply using `weak_ptr` in the child will solve the whole issue. It might be that a well chosen place for a coarser lock held higher up is a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have unique owner ship of child objects the child is guaranteed not to outlive it's parent. You could have a model something like this.

```
struct Parent;

struct Child {
        Child( Parent& p ) : p_(&p) {}
        Parent* p_;
};

#include <memory>

struct Parent {
        std::unique_ptr<Child> c_;
        void AddChild() {
                c_.reset(new Child(*this));
        }
};
```

Of course, the child should be careful with anything that it does with the parent in the destructor, it might be being destroyed because its parent is going out of scope. This is about the only advantage of a child having a `weak_ptr` to its parent (it still won't be able to do anything with the parent from its destructor but at least it can safely tell that) but this relies on its parent being owned by a `shared_ptr` which is a much more inflexible design for the child.

This would be the `weak_ptr` solution:

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED
#include <memory>

struct Parent;

struct Child {
        Child( const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& p ) : p_(p) {}
        std::weak_ptr<Parent> p_;
};

struct Parent : std::enable_shared_from_this<Parent> {
        std::unique_ptr<Child> c_;
        void AddChild() {
                // Warning, undefined behaviour if this Parent
                // isn't owner by shared_ptr
                c_.reset(new Child(shared_from_this()));
        }
};
```